# How to pass several previous states using scan in Tensorflow.

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm going to modify DRAW(Deep Recurrent Attentive Writer) code that other person shared [here](https://github.com/ericjang/draw/blob/master/draw.py) for variable length sequence using `tf.scan` function. So I need to change the for loop in the original code into a structure that is suitable for scan function. Below is original part of the code,

```
...
for t in range(T):
    c_prev = tf.zeros((batch_size,img_size)) if t==0 else cs[t-1]
    x_hat=x-tf.sigmoid(c_prev) # error image
    r=read(x,x_hat,h_dec_prev)
    h_enc,enc_state=encode(enc_state,tf.concat(1,[r,h_dec_prev]))
    z,mus[t],logsigmas[t],sigmas[t]=sampleQ(h_enc)
    h_dec,dec_state=decode(dec_state,z)
    cs[t]=c_prev+write(h_dec) # store results
    h_dec_prev=h_dec
    DO_SHARE=True # from now on, share variables
...
```

In order to use `tf.scan`, I need to pass several previous states(`c_prev`, `h_dec_prev`...). However, as I know `tf.scan` only gets one tensor (is it right?) for the loop as an example in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard9/tf.scan.md)

```
elems = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
sum = scan(lambda a, x: a + x, elems)
```

It seems there should be only one `a` and it should be a tensor. In this case, only possible way I can imagine is to flatten several different state tensors and concatenate it. But I'm worrying that it will mess up the code and make slow down the speed a lot especially when the state sizes are all different. Is there any efficient (and fast) way to handle this kind of problem?